# How do I setup an Eclipse RCP plugin to use JOGL?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jogl

I have followed the instructions on [this page](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_user_library), but when I try to run a simple [example code](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing#JOGL_in_SWT) to test it, I get an exception:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Eclipse 3.8 32-bits\natives\windows-amd64\gluegen-rt.dll

My RCP application has a few dozen plugins.  I created a new one, called stOpenGL. On this plugin's folder, I created a *lib* folder and placed in there the following files:

- gluegen-java-src.zip
- gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
- gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar
- gluegen-rt.jar
- gluegen.jar
- jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar
- jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar
- jogl-all.jar
- jogl-java-src.zip

Another plugin then sets stOpenGL as a required plugin (this plugin is where I put the simple example I mentioned before).

On the stOpenGL plugin, I tried a few combinations, to no avail:

- Put all the above files on the classpath (minus the src ones) and export all of their packages.
- Put only gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar on the classpath and export their packages.

I've tinkered with build options and some file combinations on my *lib* folder, and nothing worked.

Any ideas of what I might be missing here?

Comment: I had to do something similar about ten years ago, I had to put JOGL and GlueGen into the same plugin as far as I remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please go though this [tutorial](https://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/tutorial-a-cross-platform-workbench-program-using-java-opengl-and-eclipse/) to setup Opengl with Eclipse Plugin.

Comment: Excellent suggestion and you can contact the author of this tutorial on the official JogAmp forum: http://forum.jogamp.org

Comment: I used this tutorial in college days for one OpenGL + Eclipse RCP project

Comment: Wade's a kind guy.  I have contacted him before starting my Java/OpenGL journey and I have seen this tutorial you linked.  I'll check it out again, to make sure I didn't overlook anything.